# MSSQL filter results only with more than 2 digits after separator

Tags: sql-server

For example, I have the following result set:

```
11.2300,
23.4560,
10.4100,
12.5677,
```

Can someone please write me how to make a filter in MSSQL that will show me only these results:

```
23.4560,
12.5677
```

I want to find all the results where the last two digits are not 00.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE RIGHT(CAST(MyColumn AS Varchar(31)), 2) <> '00'
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

Using [`%`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279.aspx) (remainder/modulo division):

```
CREATE TABLE #tab(col DECIMAL(10,4));

INSERT INTO #tab(col)
VALUES (11.2300),(23.4560),(10.4100),(12.5677);

SELECT col
FROM  #tab
WHERE  col % 0.01 <> 0;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/426784)**</kbd>

Comment: @Vladi Be aware that if datatype has precision higher than 4 you will get incorrect results **[Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/426945?opt.textResults=true)**